# Nodejs stopping a loop and waiting fo the answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, promise

I want to send data within a loop. Each turn in the loop has to wait for the answer. I tried to work with Promise. The first turn in the loop works, but the problem is, that the loop stops in the first turn after the promise. Would be happy for some explanation. Thanks!

```
let dataReceived;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    dataReceived = false;
    sendInfo(arr[i]);  // send some data
    await checkDataReceived();
    console.log(i);
}

function checkDataReceived() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(dataReceived == false) {
        setTimeout(checkDataReceived, 100);
        } else {
        console.log('continue');
        // do something...
        resolve (true);
        }
    });
}

function awaitData(data){
    // do something
    dataReceived = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the snippet you have provided is to poll for a state change of a variable (`dataReceived`) and take action when succeeded. In proper patterns, the programs should try to rely on events - especially in Node JS.

Having said that, the problem you are facing is the result of the creation of new Promise objects repeatedly and never resolving them.

The `checkDataReceived` function creates a new Promise (by calling itself) every time the polling gets a false result. The original promise it returns is never resolved. So, the calling `await` statement will never succeed in the `for` loop.

Instead of calling itself, the `checkDataReceived` function should try to resolve the original promise when the polling gets a truthy result.

```
function checkDataReceived() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setInterval() => {if (dataReceived) resolve()}, 100)
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed the setTimeout() to setInterval(). Now everything works fine. Was one of my mistakes from the beginning. Thank you!

Comment: Answer edited. Yes it should be setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in checkDataReceived() function you are only using resolve(true) in else block you need to either use reject or resolve in if block as well in order to return from promise

```
function checkDataReceived() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(dataReceived == false) {
    setTimeout(checkDataReceived, 100);
      //use either resolve or reject here
    } else {
    console.log('continue');
    // do something...
    resolve (true);
    }
  });
}
```